# Can't retrieve user email address with REST API

Tags: users, rest-api, python

I would like to retrieve the email address of an user by id with the REST api from Python. The problem is I don't get the email in the JSON from the two calls I added below. Based on the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#retrieve-a-user) it should be correct with the `edit` context, but unfortunately I get back a 403 error when I call the `/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1/?context=edit`. As I am new to WP development, I would really appreciate if somebody could show me what am I doing wrong. Or any other solution to get the emails with REST.

```
wordpress_user = "username"
wordpress_password = "pass"
wordpress_credentials = wordpress_user + ":" + wordpress_password
wordpress_token = base64.b64encode(wordpress_credentials.encode())
wordpress_header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + wordpress_token.decode('utf-8')}
```

```python
    # version 
    api_url = '.../wp-json/wp/v2/users/1/' 
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    response_json = response.json()
    print (response_json)
    # version 2
    api_url = '.../wp-json/wp/v2/users/1/?context=edit' 
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    response_json = response.json()
    print (response_json)
```

Comment: are these authenticated requests? Only authenticated requests can use the `edit` context, and it must be authenticated using a user that has that ability, otherwise anybody could read the email addresses of users on a site. HTTP 403 is the forbidden access code

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, I am using the login credentials of the admin, and I would like to retrieve the email addresses of other users. Is it something what is not allowed and thats why the 403?

Comment: I'm not seeing any authentication code in your question, as far as I can see these requests are unauthenticated and not being made by any user, completely anonymous, no cookies/nonces/application passwords/etc

Comment: @TomJNowell I updated the code with the auth part. I use this setup. Is it incorrect?

Comment: I see you added some variables, but you don't use them anywhere so no that's not correct, you have to make an authenticated request, it's not enough to know the details, you have to use and apply them. Note that we can't provide python specific help here, if it's a python mistake you're making then it's highly unlikely anybody here will know enough to spot it. I can say however that while I don't know how to configure the requests library to use those credentials, I can confidently say that there is no evidence config is taking place, and the 403 response you got confirms WP doesn't either

Comment: You can't just pass the user's username and password with REST API requests. You will need to create an Application Password (edit the user's profile to see this) or implement oAuth or similar with a plugin: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins